# Show that $A^{-1}+B^{-1}$ is also invertible

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, inverse

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two invertible $n \times n$ real matrices. Assume that $A+B$ is invertible. Show that $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$ is also invertible.

---

**My approach**

\begin{aligned}
&|\mathrm{A}|\left|A^{-1}+B^{-1}\right||\mathrm{B}|=|\mathrm{B}+\mathrm{A}| \neq 0 \\
\Rightarrow &\left|A^{-1}+B^{-1}\right| \neq 0 \text { as }|\mathrm{A}|,|\mathrm{B}| \neq 0 \\
\Rightarrow & A^{-1}+B^{-1} \text {is invertible }
\end{aligned}

Am I correct? **Any other method or hint would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: Perfectly alright

Comment: $\det(A)$ looks better than $|A|$, but that doesn't count.

Comment: This is an unusual proof: How do you get the first line?  You seem to be skipping the main step of observing $A(A^{-1}+B^{-1})B=B+A$. But if you already know this, you may as well write the explicit expression $(A^{-1}+B^{-1})=A^{-1}(B+A)B^{-1}$ rather than using determinants. Anyway, the crux of the proof seems to be exactly what you are skipping.

Comment: @DietrichBurde We have the same taste :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of a slightly different approach. Let $C$ be the inverse of $A+B$ (same as $B+A)$. Then we can show that $ACB$ is the inverse of $A^{-1}+B^{-1}$.
\begin{align*}
(A^{-1}+B^{-1}) (ACB)&=CB+B^{-1}ACB\\
&=B^{-1}B (CB) +B^{-1}ACB\\
&=B^{-1}\underbrace{(B+A)C}_{=I}B\\
&=B^{-1}B\\
&=I.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael has mentioned in his comment, you are like "using the result to prove the result", or at least you could show the proof for your first line to have your solution verified without any problems...

Anyway, this answer will probably deal with this problem:

Let's assume the matrix $X$ is inverse for $A^{-1}+B^{-1}$. Then we must have
$$(A^{-1}+B^{-1})X=I \implies A^{-1}X+B^{-1}X=I$$ Now denote $Y=B^{-1}X$ to get
$$A^{-1}BY+Y=I \implies BY+AY=A \implies (A+B)Y=A$$ Since $A+B$ is invertible
$$Y=(A+B)^{-1}A$$ By substituting back we get
$$B^{-1}X=(A+B)^{-1}A \implies \boxed{X=B(A+B)^{-1}A}$$ So, we got no contradiction with this assumption.

---

Indeed, one can check that this $X$ satisfies the conditions of the inverse matrix. Let's check!

We need to show that
$$(A^{-1}+B^{-1})(B(A+B)^{-1}A)=I \ \ \ \ (1)$$
Now we use the following trick: Note that
$$B(A+B)^{-1}A + A(A+B)^{-1}A=(A+B)(A+B)^{-1}A=A \implies$$$$\implies B(A+B)^{-1}A = A -  A(A+B)^{-1}A$$ and similarly
$$B(A+B)^{-1}A + B(A+B)^{-1}B=B(A+B)^{-1}(A+B)=B \implies$$$$\implies B(A+B)^{-1}A = B -  B(A+B)^{-1}B$$
Now, back to $(1)$,
$$(A^{-1}+B^{-1})(B(A+B)^{-1}A)=(A^{-1})(A -  A(A+B)^{-1}A) + (B^{-1})(B -  B(A+B)^{-1}B)=$$$$=I - (A+B)^{-1}A + I - (A+B)^{-1}B = 2I - (A+B)^{-1}(A+B)=2I-I=I$$ And we are done!

Comment: I was lost in the beauty of the equations. Thanks a lot!